# Extract imperative sentences from a document(English) using NLP in python

Tags: python, nlp

I am very new to NLP, hence require some help on extracting imperative sentences from a document. I am working on a project where I need to get all the imperative sentences from the entire document(English documents). I understand I need to use POS tagging. But how do I proceed further.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to maximize accuracy you would need to use not only a POS tagger but also a syntactic parser. Nevertheless for this task POS tags can probably give you reasonable results indeed, here is a general method:

1. Segment the data into sentences and tokens
2. Apply the POS tagger (it predicts a POS tag for every token)
3. A [sentence is (likely) imperative](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/imperative-sentence-examples.html) if the following conditions are satisfied:

   - the sentence ends with a full stop or exclamation mark
   - the POS for the first token corresponds to a verb

This heuristic is probably all you need, but if you want to go further you could generate instances containing these features (and possibly add a few others)  for every sentence, annotate a training set and train a supervised model.

Comment: Thanks @Erwan. Your suggestion is very helpful.

Comment: POS of the first token corresponds to a verb is not always true. Consider this sentence: "You should go either late or early to avoid tourists." Not sure how much it will give false negatives.

Comment: @chandresh I agree that the method I proposed is far from perfect, it would certainly miss some cases indeed. but from a strict grammatical point of view your sentence is not in imperative mood.